# tagRAWMOUSE Structure Issues

Tags: winapi, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I have set up Raw Input to trigger `WM_INPUT` on my message window. I have set up input for mouse. I am succesfully getting messages and calling `GetRawInputData()`.

I followed the documentation to the letter but it is being a bit silly.

The docs say this is the struct I receive:

[RAWMOUSE structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645578.aspx)

So I am doing this from ctypes so this is why im getting into this.

When I do a mouse wheel up I get this:

```
tagRAWMOUSE(0, 0, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

and when I do mouse wheel down I get the exact same thing:

```
tagRAWMOUSE(0, 0, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

As a guide, when I just do a mouse move my mouse it gets this:

```
tagRAWMOUSE(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

I set up my struct with the union as 2 USHORT as my ctypes does not support union:

```
this.RAWMOUSE = ctypes.StructType('tagRAWMOUSE', [
    { usFlags: this.USHORT },
    { usButtonFlags: this.USHORT },
    { usButtonData: this.USHORT },
    { ulRawButtons: this.ULONG },
    { lLastX: this.LONG },
    { lLastY: this.LONG },
    { ulExtraInformation: this.ULONG }
]);
```

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's re-cap the C++ definition of the struct since it is important:

```
typedef struct tagRAWMOUSE {
  USHORT usFlags;
  union {
    ULONG  ulButtons;
    struct {
      USHORT usButtonFlags;
      USHORT usButtonData;
    };
  };
  ULONG  ulRawButtons;
  LONG   lLastX;
  LONG   lLastY;
  ULONG  ulExtraInformation;
} RAWMOUSE, *PRAWMOUSE, *LPRAWMOUSE;
```

The union is messing up your alignment. The union needs to be aligned so that all of its members is aligned. Because the union has a `ULONG` member, namely `ulButtons`, the union's alignment is 4 bytes. Therefore the union has to be placed at an offset that is a multiple of 4. In this case that places it at offset 4. And so there are two bytes of padding immediately after `usFlags`.

In your ctypes struct, the two `USHORT` members of the union that overlay that `ULONG`, namely `usButtonFlags` and `usButtonData` have alignment 2. Therefore they are placed at offsets 2 and 4. And the padding has been lost in translation.

This sort of thing is very common, and is one of the first things you check when translating a struct. Dig out a C++ compiler and get it to emit the size of the struct, and the offsets for all the members. Compare that with the same information from your translation. If they don't match, work out why.

You have a couple of ways to fix it:

- Replace `usButtonFlags` and `usButtonData` with a `ULONG` and use bitwise operations to pick out the two `USHORT` values.
- Add a dummy padding `USHORT` ahead of `usButtonFlags`.

Comment: Gosh thanks David, I didn't read this fully but I am right now I'm just accepting as it is so in depth im sure its right. I'm going to test it right away and report back thanks so much. This alignment lesson will teach me lots Im going to study this and I might ask some more q's here please.

Comment: For sure it's the explanation. Look at `tagRAWMOUSE(0, 0, 1024, 0, 0, 0, 0)` for mouse wheel. Well, the second arg is actually the padding. And so 1024 is `usButtonFlags` and not `usButtonData`. And `1024` in hex is `0x0400` which is, wait for it, `RI_MOUSE_WHEEL`.

Comment: Thanks that's helping I didnt try it yet Im trying to understand how come the alignment is off. Because I thought union was one or the other. So I thought if i did two `USHORT`s thats two things of size 2, so that would match perfectly and overlaps the single `ULONG`. If we put a padding of one `USHORT` between these two that will make the size of the whole struct bigger by 2 bytes no? That union field is 4 bytes no?

Comment: The union has size 4, and **alignment** 4. That means the union has to be at an offset that is a multiple of 4. I said this in the answer. That means that your struct has the padding before `ulRawButtons` but it needs to to be before the union. Definitely time to learn all about alignment.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh wait wait wait I think I see it. So if the union was just `ULONG` you have this: `|- - - -`, the bar is where the `ULONG` is and each `-` is a byte. So now if I put `USHORT` in place of the bar `|- -|- -` then that second `USHORT` is in the middle of that `ULONG`! So even if the union was just ULONG its ULONG with two padding. So really its this: `|- - - - - -` a ULONG followed by two bytes, but how do you know its not preceded by 2 bytes and followed by?. Is this common to all C stuff, like not just Winapi?

Comment: Wow I tried it now, and its really weird, its setting tagMouse to this on wheel down: `tagRAWMOUSE(0, 0, 1024, 65416, 0, 0, 0, 0)` and on wheel up its `tagRAWMOUSE(0, 0, 1024, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. If the padding was after the `ULONG` how come it didnt set the 5th element to `120`/`65416`? Thats odd no? Its setting the element that is within the non multiple of 4 alignment, the 4th element.

Comment: I don't know what you've changed.

Comment: Oh I added a USHORT padding before `usButtonData`, so after `usButtonFlags`